# Gradually color rectangles in p5js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to build a visualization of a bubble sort algorithm in browser using p5.js. I have managed to implement the algorithm and the bars are successfully switching places. Now I want to color the bars when considering them for swapping (when they are in the 'bubble', as in bubble sort). Coloring them was easy enough, but it sharply changes color, which doesn't look too good. What I want is to gradually change the color. e.g fade from blue to green. Here is my setup and draw function:

```
let bars = []; // array of Bar objects
let values = [];
let greenColor;
let blueColor;
let redColor;
let orangeColor;

function setup() {
  //Init colors
  greenColor = color(16, 112, 1);
  blueColor = color(158, 207, 224);
  redColor = color(208, 0, 46);
  orangeColor = color(253, 148, 8);  

  createCanvas(900, 900);
  textSize(15);
  // Create objects
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    values[i] = round(random(150));
    bars.push(new Bar(i*50 + i*10, values[i], -1));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    bars[i].display();
  }
}
```

The setup and draw function uses a custom class named Bar. Draw uses the Bar.display() function to draw the rectangles to screen. This is seen below:

```
display() {


if (this.colorState == 1) {
  let firstColor = blueColor;
  let secondColor = blueColor;

  if (this.currentColor == "green") {
    firstColor = greenColor;
  } else if (this.currentColor == "red") {
    firstColor = redColor;
  } else if (this.currentColor == "orange") {
    firstColor = orangeColor;
  } else {
    firstColor = blueColor;
  }

  if (this.nextColor == "green") {
    secondColor = greenColor;
  } else if (this.nextColor == "red") {
    secondColor = redColor;
  } else if (this.nextColor == "orange"){
    secondColor = orangeColor;
  } else {
    firstColor = blueColor;
  }


  if (this.amt <= 1.0) {
    var gradient = lerpColor(firstColor, secondColor, this.amt);
    this.amt += 0.05;
    fill(gradient);
  } else {
    this.colorState = 0;
    this.currentColor = this.nextColor;
    this.amt = 0;
  }


} else {
  if (this.currentColor == "green") {
    fill(greenColor);
  } else if (this.currentColor == 'blue') {
    fill(blueColor);
  } else if (this.currentColor == "red") {
    fill(redColor);
  } else {
    fill(orangeColor);
  }
}

noStroke();
rect(this.x, this.y, 50, this.height);
fill(color(0, 0, 0));
text(-this.height, this.x + 15, (height / 2) + (this.height) - 20, 60, 60);

function mouseClicked() {
    bars[0].colorState = 1;
    bars[0].nextColor = "green";
}
```

I found that using lerpColor with the amt argument allows me to gradually change the color. When I want to fade to next color, I increment it with 0.05. As of now, it fades the color OK, but then there is a blinking effect where it turns black for a couple of miliseconds and I have no idea why. Please help me fix this. Here is the js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jomzkct4/ (Scroll a bit down to see the bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a frame, when the color transition is finished `amt > 1`, where the filling color is not re-assigned so it uses the one  from the previous frame which is `fill(color(0, 0, 0))`. You can test this by adding a different color in this block of code:

```
else {
    this.colorState = 0;
    this.currentColor = this.nextColor;
    this.amt = 0;
    // Now it "blinks" red
    fill([255, 0, 0])
}
```

Ultimately you might want to reuse the logic of the color assigning for when the `colorState` value is `0` or tweak the logic of the `if (this.colorState == 1) {...} else{...}` block.

```js
let bars = []; // array of Bar objects
let values = [];
let greenColor;
let blueColor;
let redColor;
let orangeColor;

function setup() {
  //Init colors
  greenColor = color(16, 112, 1);
  blueColor = color(158, 207, 224);
  redColor = color(208, 0, 46);
  orangeColor = color(253, 148, 8);  

  createCanvas(900, 900);
  textSize(15);
  frameRate(10)
  // Create objects
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    values[i] = round(random(150));
    bars.push(new Bar(i*50 + i*10, values[i], -1));
    
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    bars[i].display();
  }
}

// Bar class
class Bar {
  constructor(xCord, heightIn) {
    this.x = xCord;
    this.y = height / 2;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.height = -heightIn;
    this.currentColor = "blue";
    this.nextColor = "blue";
    this.amt = 0;
    this.colorState = 0; //0 for static, 1 for changing
  }
  display() {
    if (this.colorState == 1) {
      let firstColor = blueColor;
      let secondColor = blueColor;

      if (this.currentColor == "green") {
        firstColor = greenColor;
      } else if (this.currentColor == "red") {
        firstColor = redColor;
      } else if (this.currentColor == "orange") {
        firstColor = orangeColor;
      } else {
        firstColor = blueColor;
      }

      if (this.nextColor == "green") {
        secondColor = greenColor;
      } else if (this.nextColor == "red") {
        secondColor = redColor;
      } else if (this.nextColor == "orange"){
        secondColor = orangeColor;
      } else {
        firstColor = blueColor;
      }


      if (this.amt <= 1.0) {
        var gradient = lerpColor(firstColor, secondColor, this.amt);
        this.amt += 0.05;
        fill(gradient);
      } 
      
      else {
        this.colorState = 0;
        this.currentColor = this.nextColor;
        this.amt = 0;
       
//      Either reuse the logic:

       /*  if (this.currentColor == "green") {
          fill(greenColor);
        } else if (this.currentColor == 'blue') {
          fill(blueColor);
        } else if (this.currentColor == "red") {
          fill(redColor);
        } else {
          fill(orangeColor);
        } */
      }
    } 
    
//       or tweak the logic of the if-else block
    
    //else{
    
    if (this.colorState == 0) {
      if (this.currentColor == "green") {
        fill(greenColor);
      } else if (this.currentColor == 'blue') {
        fill(blueColor);
      } else if (this.currentColor == "red") {
        fill(redColor);
      } else {
        fill(orangeColor);
      }
    }

    noStroke();
    rect(this.x, this.y, 50, this.height);
    fill(color(0, 0, 0));
    text(-this.height, this.x + 15, (height / 2) + (this.height) - 20, 60, 60);
  }
}


function mouseClicked() {
    bars[0].colorState = 1;
    bars[0].nextColor = "green";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW, The version of p5.js that you use on your jsfiddle link is very outdated.

Comment: Reusing the logic in the else statement stopped the "blinking", thank you! I used a p5 jsfiddle template which is why it is so old, I have the newest version in my own project, thanks for pointing it out though!